# Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse

Tags: oracle, deployment, weblogic, enterprise, pack

I'm trying to setup a development environement with Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse.

I successfully deployed my EAR to WebLogic 10.3.3.

If I modify Java / JSP resources, everything is deployed instantly to the WebLogic server.
But for other web resources, such as as JS or CSS, I do not have the the changes deployed instantly : I have to click on the "publish" button on the server view to see it (and that causes my application to restart).

Is there anything to configure to "hot deploy" web resources ?

Edit : fast-swap is switched on :

```
<weblogic-application>
<library-ref>
    <library-name>jsf</library-name>
    <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
    <implementation-version>1.0.0.0_2-0-2</implementation-version>
    <exact-match>false</exact-match>
</library-ref>

<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>

<fast-swap>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</fast-swap>

</weblogic-application>
```

Thank you.

Mathieu.

Comment: Do you clear your browser cache after updating the resources, but before publishing?

Comment: I tried to clear browser cache before or after publishing, doesn't affect the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try enabling FastSwap in your weblogic-application.xml
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13702/deployunits.htm#DEPGD156

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer. yes I-ve switched fast swap on - see the weblogic-application.xml added in my question.

Comment: Anyway isn't fast-swap functionnality used for java class reloading only ? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/deployment/deployunits.html#wp1053872